# Get all entities from Google Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I "stole" this example from Google documentation:

```
function listTasks() {
  const query = datastore.createQuery('Task').order('created');

  datastore
    .runQuery(query)
    .then(results => {
      const tasks = results[0];

      console.log('Tasks:');
      tasks.forEach(task => {
        const taskKey = task[datastore.KEY];
        console.log(taskKey.id, task);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
}
```

It didn't work at first but after I found an answer on SO about login thingy now I see some results. The problem is... I am trying to display all the entities from 1 collection. Collection called "Tasks" since it was also taken from the docs. It has only 1 entry right now:

[image: 1 task in collection]

I see only `Tasks:` displayed in the console without any information from the actual DB. Is there anything wrong with the official code?

Comment: Do you mean that `tasks` only has one item or that all items show the same task key ID?

Comment: @Oliver no, all I see is this `console.log('Tasks:');` I don't see lines generated with `forEach` at all but I should be seeing 1 entry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I am slow. So the problem was that `.order('created')` isn't a "built-in" functionality, I don't have that property in my collection so nothing to sort by. Weird that it wasn't causing an error because of that, but without it everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. You should accept your own answer.